# Why does classification accuracy of K-means clustering decrease with more training data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to classify actions from videos. For this purpose, K-means clustering is applied to optical flow points to generate a codebook.

With `k=200`, accuracy is initially 85%. After adding training data, accuracy is 50%. If `k=400`, accuracy is back to 85%.

How can the value of `k` be automatically optimized for my training data?

Comment: Welcome to machine learning. Unfortunately there is no one answer fits all problems.

Comment: K-means is pretty unstable on some data. Run it several times and you can get pretty diverse results - that usually indicates that none of them is good. So you may also have some evaluation problem. "Accuracy" is not commonly used in clustering.

Comment: k-means clustering was used to create a codebook. The above stated accuracy is of the final classifier.

Answer (score 2):

KMeans clustering will reduce your MSE and the answer for an optimum number of clusters is "It Depends". You can use elbow method to find optimum number of clusters. Here is one [link](https://blog.cambridgespark.com/how-to-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-for-k-means-clustering-14f27070048f) that you can go through to find more details.

Comment: i tried elbow method from [here](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html) and it took hours with just to plot 5 different k values

Comment: Is there any method which will yield a result in shorter computation time?

Comment: Unfortunately No. I think all of them will take time. You can try the average silhouette and gap statistic.

Comment: Average silhouette score plot has spikes to both +1 and -1 region and i couldn't interpret it. I'll try gap statistics